# counting duplicate objects in an array php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, duplicates, counting

I have an array of objects retrieved from an larvel sql query:

```
$c=[{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}, {hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 13},…]
0: {hashtag_id: 5}
1: {hashtag_id: 5}
2: {hashtag_id: 13}
3: {hashtag_id: 2}
4: {hashtag_id: 13}
5: {hashtag_id: 5}
6: {hashtag_id: 13}
7: {hashtag_id: 5}
8: {hashtag_id: 12}
9: {hashtag_id: 13}
10: {hashtag_id: 2}
11: {hashtag_id: 12}
12: {hashtag_id: 13}
13: {hashtag_id: 5}
14: {hashtag_id: 12}
15: {hashtag_id: 13}
```

I am trying to count through the array and take a count for each hashtag_id.

Expected output:

```
hashtag_id: 2 {2};
hashtag_id: 5 {5}; 
hashtag_id: 12 {3}; 
hashtag_id:13 {6};
```

OR
expected output:

```
hashtag_id: 2 count: 2;
hashtag_id: 5 count: 5;
hashtag_id:12 count: 3;
hashtag_id:13 count: 5;
```

what would be the best way about doing this?

My Code:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($result2);$j++){
                $all2 = HashtagFollow::select('hashtag_id')->where('user_id', $result2[$j]->user_id)->whereNotIn('hashtag_id', $all)->orderBy('hashtag_id')->get();
                array_push($c, $all2);
            }
        $c1 = array_flatten($c);
$d = (array_count_values(array_column($c1, 'hashtag_id')));
return ($d);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: returns an error message: "array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!"

Comment: Maybe you could group by hashtag_id and count in the query? Seems like it could simplify things

Comment: If you want to go the array_count_values route, try getting an array of the hashtag_id int values using array_column

Comment: that worked thank you

Comment: @Don'tPanic how can i go about sorting them in order by highest count?

Comment: `rsort` should do it. No wait, `arsort`. `rsort` will reindex it.

Comment: message: "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."  This is how it is returned beforehand {2: 2, 5: 5, 12: 3, 13: 6}
2: 2
5: 5
12: 3
13: 6

Comment: The message from what? Is this still related to the sorting/grouping, or something after that?

Comment: yes the return is from when i used $d = array_count_values(array_column($c1, 'hashtag_id'));  the error message is from when i tried both rsort and arsort on $d.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what happened. `arsort` takes the array by reference, sorts the array and returns a boolean rather than the sorted array. So it's not like `$x = arsort($d); return $x;` instead it's just `arsort($d); return $d;`.

Comment: came out the same way as before.2: 2
5: 5
12: 3
13: 6. I need it it like 13: 6, 5: 5, 12: 3, 2: 2. and thank you for the help

Comment: That's weird, arsort should work. Check this example: https://3v4l.org/EMIH2

Comment: still no luck r sort work but i lose the key value associated with it.[6, 5, 3, 2]
0: 6
1: 5
2: 3
3: 2

Comment: Can you include the code you're using in your question? Maybe I can help figure out what's going wrong

Comment: I just put some of the code in there